# select first rows in oracle without full table scan

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to perform the following query in Oracle.

```
select * from (select rownum r, account from fooTable) where r<5001;
```

It selects the 1st 5000 rows. I'm running into a problem that fooTable has a lot of data inside of it and this is really slowing down the query (35 million+ rows). According to the query analyzer it's performing a full table scan.

My question is, is there a way to speed up this statement? Since I'm only fetching the 1st N rows, is the full table scan necessary?

mj

Comment: Put a where clause in your subquery.

Comment: Yes a full table scan is exactly the best and fastest way to perform this query (it won't actually perform a FULL scan of the table, it will scan the first 5000 rows of the table).

Comment: Is that your exact query, or does your real query have joins in it, or an ORDER BY clause, or some other stuff we can't see?

Comment: Think of a table like a book.  If you want to find only pages with references to X on them, look up X in the index.  If you want to read the first 50 pages of the book then - just read the first 50 pages ("full scan")

Comment: If you have an option then you might want to use order by clause in your subquery. Index on column in where clause may improve query performance.

Comment: @TonyAndrews this is the exact query. Nothing else. I'm fetching this data because I want to use it to build a new table full of sample testing data. I don't care about the order. I'm not sure that it's scanning just the first 5k rows. It's taking forever. If I change it to 10 it's still terrible.

Comment: Does this work any better?: `select account from fooTable where rownum < 5001;`.  `fooTable` isn't a view is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the `/*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */` hint to be very helpful in cases like this (such as for limiting pagination results). You replace `n` with whatever value you want.

```
select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(5000) */
  account 
from fooTable
where rownum <5000;
```

You still need the `rownum` predicate to limit rows, but the hint lets the optimizer know you only need a lazy fetch of `n` rows.